# Arduino IDE maximum PROGMEM char array length

Tags: arduino, progmem

I am trying to use a single 4KB string in my arduino sketch but this always seems to give a whole bunch of java errors in the console and never compiles. I believe, I am using it correctly:

```
const char sequence[] PROGMEM = {"0F0FF0 ... 0F0F0FF"};
```

By trial-and-error I determined that the maximum length I can get to compile successfully is 1104 characters. This doesn't seem to make much sense. Is there some unknown limitation in the compiler or is it an issue with the IDE? I'm using 1.0.5 but I get the same results in 1.6.5 as well. I'd really rather not split the array. Reading online, the size limit should be 32KB, which is far higher, than what I need. 
Any help or explanation appreciated, please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a limitation of the IDE, not the compiler. If you make it a single string still, but use C's string concatenation, it will compile. eg.

```
const char sequence[] PROGMEM = {
"0F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF0"
"0F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF0"
...
"0F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF00F0F0FF0"
};
```